# Unit-testing datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, python-datetime, python-unittest.mock

Can someone help me to unit test this line of code?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

def get_timestamp_plus_100_year():
    return int((datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(days=100 * 365)).timestamp())
```

I try this, but I don't know how to assign the values:

```
@patch("src.shared.utils.timedelta")
@patch("src.shared.utils.datetime")
def test_get_timestamp_now_plus_100_years(self, mock_datetime, mock_timedelta):
    mock_datetime.now.return_value = 2021-09-14 15:54:25.284087+00:00
    mock_timedelta.return_value = 36500 days, 0:00:00

    self.assertEqual(
        get_timestamp_plus_100_year(),
        int((mock_datetime.now.return_value 
             + mock_timedelta.return_value).timestamp_return_value ),
    )
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? Note that not every year has 365 days.

Answer (score 3):

Correct the implementation first. As pointed out by @MrFuppes, not all years are 365 days. Assuming today is `2021-9-15`, your original implementation would result to:

```
>>> datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(days=100 * 365)
datetime.datetime(2121, 8, 22, 9, 19, 30, 468735, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Here, you can see that instead of the expected `2121-9-15`, what we got was `2121-8-22`.

**Option 1:** Using [datetime.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) to replace the `year` with `year+100`

```
>>> (dt := datetime.now(timezone.utc)).replace(year=dt.year + 100)
datetime.datetime(2121, 9, 15, 9, 24, 52, 139984, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

**Option 2:** Using [dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html#module-dateutil.relativedelta) to add `+100` years. This requires `pip install python-dateutil`.

```
>>> datetime.now(timezone.utc) + relativedelta(years=100)
datetime.datetime(2121, 9, 15, 9, 28, 16, 789807, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Then, you don't need to mock the `timedelta` (or `relativedelta` in our corrected code) since its value will always be 100 years. You just need to mock the current date via `datetime.now()` since it is the base of the addition and we need to assert the result.

Assuming this is the file tree:

```
.
├── src.py
└── test_src.py
```

**src.py**

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


def get_timestamp_plus_100_year():
    return int((datetime.now(timezone.utc) + relativedelta(years=100)).timestamp())
```

#### Solution 1:

```
from datetime import datetime
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

from src import get_timestamp_plus_100_year


class TestDates(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("src.datetime")
    def test_get_timestamp_now_plus_100_years(self, mock_datetime):
        frozen_dt = datetime(year=2021, month=9, day=15)
        mock_datetime.now.return_value = frozen_dt

        # Solution 1.1
        self.assertEqual(
            get_timestamp_plus_100_year(),
            int((frozen_dt + relativedelta(years=100)).timestamp()),
        )

        # Solution 1.2
        frozen_dt_100 = datetime(year=2121, month=9, day=15)  # Since we already know the value of +100 years, we can just define it here
        self.assertEqual(
            get_timestamp_plus_100_year(),
            int(frozen_dt_100.timestamp()),
        )
```

#### Solution 2

This requires [freezegun](https://pypi.org/project/freezegun/) via `pip install freezegun`

```
from datetime import datetime
import unittest

from freezegun import freeze_time

from src import get_timestamp_plus_100_year


@freeze_time("2021-09-15")  # Either here
class TestDates(unittest.TestCase):
    @freeze_time("2021-09-15")  # Or here
    def test_get_timestamp_now_plus_100_years_2(self):
        frozen_dt_100 = datetime(year=2121, month=9, day=15)  # Since we already know the value of +100 years, we can just define it here
        self.assertEqual(
            get_timestamp_plus_100_year(),
            int(frozen_dt_100.timestamp()),
        )
```